# Turn a MATLAB plot into image

Tags: matlab, filtering, plot, rasterizing

I have generated a plot like

```
figure; hold;
axis([0 10 0 10]);
fill([ 1 1 5 5], [5 1 1 5],'b')
```

and now I want to have this plot as an matrix so that I can i.e. filter the blog with a gaussian. Googleing I found this thread [Rasterizing Plot to Image](http://www.mathworks.co.jp/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/256895) at MATLAB Central. I tried it, but I could only get it to work for line or function plots.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I know, I made the example too simple / trivial. But with the answer I marked, one can rasterize even arbitrary plots easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use GETFRAME function. It returns movie frame structure, which is actually rasterized figure. Field cdata will contain your matrix.

```
F=getframe;
figure(2)
imagesc(F.cdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the desired characteristics of your target matrix ?  And what sort of images do you want to rasterise ?

You see, for the only example you have given us it's almost trivial to define a matrix representing your image ...

```
1. figmat = ones(10,10,3) % create a 10x10 raster where each entry is a triple for RGB, setting them all to 1 colours the whole raster white
2. figmat(2:5,2:5,1:2) = 0 % sets RG components in the coloured area to 0, leaving only blue
```

Your matrix is a raster to start with.  Now, you can use the built-in function image to visualise your matrix. Have a look at the documentation for that function.  And note that my suggestion does not meet the spec for use with image() and colormap().