# In matlab, how to draw a grid over an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to draw a grid over an image. It should become part of that image itself.
It should be able to show some rows and columns over the image itself. The lines for rows and columns can be specified.
Actually I was encouraged by the way some research paper discusses about the results they have about image warping. One of the links is this: http://www.hammerhead.com/thad/morph.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a number of related questions on SO that discuss ways to modify an image. Here are the two general approaches:

**1. Modify the image data directly:** I discuss this in [my answer to this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/575519/52738). Since image data can be [2-D or 3-D](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html), you can use [multidimensional indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html#f1-86846) to modify the raw image data, creating lines along given rows and columns. Here's an example that changes every 10 rows and columns in the image to black:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');  %# Load a sample 3-D RGB image
img(10:10:end,:,:) = 0;       %# Change every tenth row to black
img(:,10:10:end,:) = 0;       %# Change every tenth column to black
imshow(img);                  %# Display the image
```

[image]

And now the image data in the variable `img` has black lines on it, and you can write it to a file or do whatever other processing you want to it.

**2. Plot the image and the lines, then turn the axes/figure into a new image:** The [link to Steve Eddins' blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/01/01/superimposing-line-plots/) in [zellus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181946/52738) shows an example of how you can plot an image and add lines to it. However, if you want to save or perform processing on the *displayed* image, you will have to save the displayed image as an image matrix. How you can do this has been discussed in these other SO questions:

- [How can I save an altered image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/575475/52738)
- [Turn Matlab plot into image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915891/52738)

Comment: I felt the example code in '1.Modify the image data directly' was bit simpler. Section '2.Plot the image and line ...' was helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

[Superimposing line plots on images](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/01/01/superimposing-line-plots/) from the blog 'Steve on Image Processing' has a nice example on overlaying a grid over an image.

Comment: Thanks, this was the simplest example I saw.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I watched this question after doing this code by my own .... the code reads an image and draw grid on the image every input parameter

I hope it would do any good  :)

Watch the matlab code :

```
function [ imageMatdouble ] = GridPicture( PictureName , countForEachStep )
 %This function grid the image into counts grid 
pictureInfo = imfinfo(PictureName);     %load information about the input 

 [inputImageMat, inputImageMap] = imread(PictureName);        % Load the image     

 if (pictureInfo.ColorType~='truecolor')
    warning('The function works only with RGB (TrueColor) picture');
    return 
 end

%1. convert from trueColor(RGB) to intensity (grayscale)
 imageMat = rgb2gray(inputImageMat);   

%2. Convert image to double precision.
 imageMatdouble =im2double(imageMat);  

 % zero is create indicated to black 
 height = pictureInfo.Height ; 
 width = pictureInfo.Width
  i=1;j=1;  
 while (i<=height ) 
     for j=1:width
         imageMatdouble(i,j)=1;
    end
    j=1;
    if (i==1)
       i=i+countForEachStep-1;
   else 
       i=i+countForEachStep;
   end
  end


   i=1;j=1;  
  while (i<=width ) 
  for j=1:height
      imageMatdouble(j,i)=1;
   end
  j=1;
  if (i==1)
      i=i+countForEachStep-1;
  else 
       i=i+countForEachStep;
   end

 end

 imwrite(imageMatdouble,'C:\Users\Shahar\Documents\MATLAB\OutputPicture.jpg')



 end
```