# Count number of grid boxes which cover an object in an image

Tags: matlab

I have displayed grid boxes over an image. I want to count number of grid boxes which cover an object in that image 
for example http://snag.gy/geFIZ.jpg. In this image I have displayed grid on image but i need to count how many girds have been taken to cover that object completely.? Kindly help me regarding this

Regards 
Dams

Comment: This question is at great risk for being closed as not a real question. Please remember this is not a help forum it is a question and answer site. Please tell us what you've tried and why it failed. Please ask concrete questions on what you're stuck based on what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Slow, but easy to implement way:

1) Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181913/in-matlab-how-to-draw-a-grid-over-an-image?rq=1) topic to add lines to image.
2) Make something like this:
Make a cycle to check every box. In each box check pixels. If you found first white pixel in box, add 1 to number of covering boxes and go for next one.

No code from you - no code from me, sorry :) Good luck!