# Displaying gridlines in MATLAB imagesc function

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I have been trying to display solid black gridlines using the imagesc function, such that each pixel has a black boundary around it. I have tried a few methods, but it seems that no matter what, the lines always go through the pixel. As an example, for imagesc(randn(21,21)), I am trying to get a plot where each square (ie. pixel) here has a black border.

I found one solution here: [In matlab, how to draw a grid over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181913/in-matlab-how-to-draw-a-grid-over-an-image), but I am unsure how to get it to work with imagesc, and not a.jpg image.

I have also tried using the hold on function to place the lines manually. But every solution, it seems that the grid lines pass through the middle of the pixel. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

[`pcolor`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) does exactly that:

```
pcolor(randn(15,21))
axis image %// equal scale on both axes
axis ij %// use if you want the origin at the top, like with imagesc
```

[image]

Comment: a fundamental difference is that `pcolor` colors the vertices instead of the cells, whereas `imagesc` colors the cells... one should take care with simply going from `imagesc` to `pcolor` because the contents will be displaced; check it: `figure;pcolor(hadamard(20));title('pcolor');set(gca,'YDir','Reverse');figure;imagesc(hadamard(20))`

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
imagesc(randn(21,21))
hold on;
for i = 1:22
   plot([.5,21.5],[i-.5,i-.5],'k-');
   plot([i-.5,i-.5],[.5,21.5],'k-');
end
```

**EDIT:** The thing is the centers of the pixels are at the integer lattice points, so to outline the pixels you need to use coordinates that ends on .5.

Answer (score 2):

### Extention to @luis-mendo 's answer

As @Girardi mentioned, pcolor displaces the matrix contents. For example:

```
i = eye(5);
pcolor(i);
axis image %// equal scale on both axes
axis ij %// use if you want the origin at the top, like with imagesc
```

gives [image: Note: Shows 4x4 instead of 5x5]

Note that it gives `4x4` instead of `5x5`. **Solution:** Pad the matrix with zeros

---

```
i = eye(5);
pcolor([i, zeros(size(i,1), 1); zeros(1, size(i,2)+1)])
axis image %// equal scale on both axes
axis ij %// use if you want the origin at the top, like with imagesc
axis off
```

gives

[image: Correct]

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to highlight the diagonal do the following:

```
    mat=rand(10);
    figure, imagesc(mat)
    colormap gray

    hold on;
    n=size(mat,1);
    for i = 1:n
       plot([.5,n+.5],[i-.5,i-.5],'k-');
       plot([i-.5,i-.5],[.5,n+.5],'k-');
    end

    % Highlight diagonal values
    k=0.5;
    for i=1:numel(diag(mat))
    line([k, i+.5], [i+.5, i+.5], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
    k=k+1;
    end

    k=0.5;
    for i=1:numel(diag(mat))
    line([k, i+.5], [k, k], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
    k=k+1;
    end

    k=0.5;
    for i=1:numel(diag(mat))
    line([i+.5, i+.5], [k, i+.5], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
    k=k+1;
    end

    k=0.5;
    for i=1:numel(diag(mat))
    line([k, k], [k, i+.5], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
    k=k+1;
    end
```