# Possible to save figures into variables instead of files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have Matlab code such as:

```
f=figure(1)
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(x1,y1)
hold on
...
plot(xf, yf)
%want to save this into a VARIABLE, NOT into a .fig, .png, jpg, or other kind of file
```

So if it is possible to save this into some variable `var_fig`, I would like to later open the figure (such as in a subplot with multiple saved figures/plots) doing something like

```
showfig(var_fig)
```

Is this possible in Matlab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn a MATLAB plot into image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915891/turn-a-matlab-plot-into-image)

Comment: Another way of solving the problem of 'preserving figure data' in general is to store the raw-data in a file and load it at the beginning of your 'plot figure' script. In this case, you would only store `x,y,x1,y1,xf,yf` in a *.mat file using the save command above, then load your data before executing your figure script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible but not recommended. You can save any variable using `save`:

```
myfigure = gcf; %store current figure in a variable
save('filename','myfigure');
```

However according to Matlab be warned:

```
Warning: Figure is saved in filename.mat. Saving graphics handle variables
can cause the creation of very large files. To save graphics figures,
use savefig.
```

Here's how to use [savefig](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html)